# Can anyone identify this device hooked to water pipes

Tags: plumbing

This device is between the hot and cold water pipes in a brand new building, in Germany.

What is it for?

[image]

Comment: Wild guess... A thermometer on the left controlling a valve on the right, possibly as an anti-scald mechanism. This would require mixing downstream of course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Honeywell V5012 Kombi-DP Diaphragm Unit.  Details in the URL below.  To quote a section:

> It is used in systems with variable volume flows, for example two-pipe
>   heating systems or district heating exchangers, and supports a
>   hydronic balance by keeping the differential pressure over consumers
>   at a constant pre-set level even under changing flow conditions.

[Honeywell V5012](https://m.productcatalog.honeywellhome.com/turkey/pdf/v5012c-pd-en0h0281ge25r0805.pdf)

Comment: To simplify, those things on the pipes are valves. The diaphragm setup with the connecting tube will throttle the inlet line valve or the return line valve to balance flow across the system. These are used on heating (or cooling) systems to account for pressure changes on the supply side.

Comment: Is the ugly loop of copper required?  I mean is there a minimum length?  Would have been a far more elegant install if the red valve had been above the blue with one simple 90 degree bend, not 630 degrees of bending.

Comment: Copper pipes under pressure are often given a bend to allow them to flex under pressure and to inhibit fluid hammer. Not sure that's the reason here, but it could be.

Comment: @Criggie See item 9 in the V5012 installation guide at the end of the link. A possible reason is that the loop makes the connecting pipe more flexible in all possible misalignment directions, and therefore avoids any unwanted loads on the end connectors. The OP's picture looks like somebody made a poor imitation of the pre-supplied connecting pipe.